# Unable to compile and link main.c to another source file using gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compilation, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying to compile the following source file using `gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -o main  -lm`.

### source.h

```
void simple_sum(void)
```

### source.c

```
    #include "source.h"
    #include <stdio.h>

    void simple_sum(void)
    {
        int a, b;
        scanf("%d %d", &a, &b);
        printf("%d + %d = %d\n",a, b, a + b);
    }
```

### main.c

```
#include "source.h"                                                                                                     
#include <stdio.h>  

int main(void)                                                                                                          
{                                                                                                                           
    printf("\n");                                                                                                           
    simple_sum();     

    return 0;                                                                                                           
}
```

I get following error:

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -o main  -lm
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function _start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'main' failed
make: *** [main] Error 1
```

Could someone please suggest how to fix this?

### Edit

I get the following error when I run using `gcc -g -Wall main.c -o main`

`/tmp/ccEAL4iG.o: In function`main':
/home/a/aalto_university/functions/calculation/main.c:7: undefined reference to `simple_sum'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: The command you show can't be correct since you don't seem to pass *any* source file as argument. How would the compiler know what your source files are if you don't tell it?

Comment: You also forgot a senicolon in source.h.

Comment: Now how do you think you would *add* the second source file when building?

Comment: I forgot to include the semicolon in this post. I think there is something wrong with the Bash for Windows application. The main.c is getting deleted!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -o main  -lm
```

you are not providing *source file name* to linker, hence it throw error like

> undefined reference to `main'

While compiling provide source file `main.c` and `source.c`. For e.g first run this

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -c main.c source.c -lm
```

to create the object`.o` files & then create the executable by running

```
gcc source.o main.o -o my_exe
```

And finally run the executable. Also declaration of `simple_sum()` missing `;` it should be

```
void simple_sum(void); /* you miss ;*/
```

Also learn how to use [Makefile](https://askubuntu.com/questions/333786/what-is-a-makefile-exactly-and-how-we-can-create-one) for compilation as @Basile pointed, there you don't have to create `.o` file manually, your `Makefile` will create `.o` file & compile if it's written correctly.

Comment: I get this`/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/5/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x20): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`

Comment: should be gcc main.c source.c -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -o my_prog -lm

Comment: @NickS order doesn't matter much here I think & if you read `man 1 gcc`, it syntax is `gcc [-c|-S|-E] [-std=standard]
           [-g] 
           [-Wpedantic]
           [-o outfile] [@file] infile`

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the Bash for Windows application. The main.c is getting deleted!!

Comment: @achal yes sure, but this solution doesn’t work because there is *.c files provided as output

Comment: @Alokananda your bash is fine, but this answer isn't. See the 2 previous comments.

Comment: @Jabberwocky It started working fine after I restarted Bash!

Comment: @achal now after your edit, the .c fiule isn't deleted anymore, but the final executable won't be created by `gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -c main.c source.c -lm`, it only creates `main.o` and `source.o`; the link stepp is missing: `gcc -o executable main.o main.o` needs to be there as well.

Comment: @achal OK dv retracted

Answer (score 4):

Compile with

```
 gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 source.c main.c -o myprog -lm
```

(actually, `-lm` is not needed, you don't use `<math.h>` functions; but keeping `-lm` should not harm)

Later, [learn](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/index.html) to write your `Makefile` to do these things in several steps:

First, get the `source.o` object file with

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -c source.c
```

then get the `main.o` object file with

```
gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -std=c99 -c main.c
```

At last, link both of them

```
gcc -g source.o main.o -lm -o myprog
```

Comment: I think there is something wrong with the Bash for Windows application. The main.c is getting deleted!!